# How do I use Ubuntu Server and OpenStack to create my own private cloud, which can host a website and store data on it?

Tags: server, openstack, cloud

I want to use Ubuntu OpenStack to create my own server from scratch which will help me deploy my own cloud application. How do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/installing-ubuntu-openstack-2015-06-01/

In my opinion if you are new to Cloud, go with Citrix Xenserver or something like that first, free and easy to use.